# open pdf from asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

I have PDF that I would like to open from ASP.net project. I don't want to navigate to the PDF, but I want to keep the current page opened but when a user clicks on the link, I want to open the PDF file in another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could open the PDF in a new window:

```
 <asp:HyperLink  Target="_blank" runat="server" ID="linkBarPdf" Text="Open Bar PDF"
                 NavigateUrl="~/foo/bar.pdf">
```

This won't *host* the PDF though, but rather serve up the file for execution by the local machine's viewer. That COULD be a browser plug-in, or it could be outside of the browser.

Comment: you can also do this with a straight up HTML hyperlink and avoid the <asp:HyperLink> wrapper object.

Comment: @Visionary: indeed. I figured I'd give an ASP.NET solution rather than an HTML-only. Perhaps there is some code-behind involved here, and perhaps some reliance on viewstate.